# How do I make this Web Crawler infinite?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, python-requests

This is the code I'm trying to write, (A web crawler that loops through a list of links, where the first link is the original and then the links on the sites are appended to the list and the for loop keeps going through the list, for some reason the script keeps stopping when around 150 links are appended and printed)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

links = ['http://example.com']
def spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    number = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        try:
            for LINK in links:
                url = LINK
                source_code = requests.get(url)
                plain_text = source_code.text
                soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
                for link in soup.findAll("a"):
                    try:
                        href = link.get("href")
                        if href.startswith("http"):
                            if href not in links:
                                number += 1
                                links.append(href)
                                print("{}: {}".format(number, href))
                    except:
                        pass

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

while True:
    spider(10000)
```

What do I do to make it infinite?

Comment: Try printing out the exceptions instead of ignoring them, my guess is that most iterations of the loop result in an error

Comment: Maybe your code is working perfectly and the website has only 150 pages.

Comment: I'm blushing, but wouldn't so many links, almost 200, link to way more as well?

Comment: I added an "except Exception as e: print(e)" and got back "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'", so obviously one of the strings isn't acting like one, or am I wrong? How do I fix this?

Comment: That error looks like it occurs when you find an `<a>` element that has no `href` attribute. You should check that the link actually has a href before you try to call `startswith` on it.

Comment: I changed my code, I did what you said, thank you so much, I wish I could approve your answer but it is a comment, so if you want post an answer and Ill tick it off, thank you @Kevin!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error looks like it occurs when you find an `<a>` element that has no `href` attribute. You should check that the link actually has a href before you try to call startswith on it.

Comment: Thank you Kevin, I really appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Samir Chahine,

Your Code is failing because,  because the href variable is none in

```
href = link.get("href")
```

so put another check there as :

```
if (href is not none) and href.startswith("http://")
```

Plz convert the logic in python code

```
    try to debug using print statement like :



href = link.get("href")
                        print("href "+ href)
                        if href is not none and href.startswith("http"):
                            print("Condition passed 1")
                            if href not in links:
                                print("Condition passed 2")
                                number += 1
                                links.append(href)
                                print("{}: {}".format(number, href))
```

Comment: Sometimes I get "('Connection aborted.', gaierror(11001, 'getaddrinfo failed'))", why?

Comment: I added your bit of code to my program and now it's not printing anything at all?

Comment: try to debug using print statement like :
  
      href = link.get("href")
      print("href "+ href)
                        if href is not none and href.startswith("http"):
       print("Condition passed 1")
                            if href not in links:
        print("Condition passed 2")
                                number += 1
                                links.append(href)
                                print("{}: {}".format(number, href))

Comment: For that error u can check this link :  https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.gaierror

Comment: This type of error comes, when the server is not reachable. You need to catch those error. You can verify by printing that link which gives you error, and then hitting that link using your browser. I expect browser will also show some error.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, can you please edit that into my code?

Comment: Updated the answer..Look at that

Comment: Let me know the ouput

Comment: The output is a infinite loop of the same links?

Comment: can you paste the link

Comment: What do you mean paste the link?

Comment: paste the output of this line :   print("href "+ href)

Comment: I think what I told it to do was only print a link once but your alteration is telling it to print any link finds as many times as it finds it

Comment: The none links are 
"href #" and "href #content"

Comment: and that's when it loops

Comment: yeah i understand because it does not able to pass that if condition, hence the same link is getting printed. Have u properly converted my logic to  python code and paste that repetitive link please.

Comment: I don't actually know what you mean by covert your logic to python?

Comment: Means the logic which I provided may not be in proper python code. So Hopefully you understand my logic and converted it into python code if necessary.

Comment: Yeah I tried, and I have no idea what to do from here, it keeps looping the "#"